# how to get the absolute difference in elements between two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

There are many examples on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any that handled duplicate values in the way I need.

Given

```
a=  [a, a, b]
b=   [a, b]
```

I want the result to be

```
result = returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(a,b)
//result = [a]

result = returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(b,a)
// result = []
```

or let’s say I have:

```
a2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
b2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

I want to get:

```
result = returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(a2,b2)
//console.log(result) = [4]

result = returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(b2,a2)
//console.log(result) = [3]
```

the difference and symmetrical difference shown here
[How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571156/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

don't work. They empty arrays because it's checking only values, not instances of elements... the problem is I care about the number of elements of a value, not just the value.

Comment: no sir, tired it. returned empty arrays because it's checking only values, not instances of elements... the problem is I care about the number of elements of a value, not just the value.

Comment: How are you going about this? It's hard to answer questions without any actual code.

Comment: Why does first example returns empty `filtered_b` but in second example `b_2` has difference?

Comment: I still don't understand it. Why `(a,b)` returns difference but `(b,a)` doesn't? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: @Jax-p it's not a difference per se, more a "minus": _what's left over in `a` when you remove all the elements from it that exist in `b`_.

Comment: edited again.

function should return all elements in a that are not in b

Comment: yeah, I want the absolute difference, not difference in represented values...

Comment: Why is your fourth result empty? Shouldn't it be `[3]`?

Comment: yes,sorry! you are correct. should be [3] (edited question to fix)

Answer (score 0):

```
const uniqueDifference = (added, removed) => {
  if (added.length === 0) return [[], removed]

  const [x, ...xs] = added
  const idx = removed.findIndex(y => x === y)

  if (idx > -1) {
    return uniqueDifference(xs, removed.filter((_, i) => i !== idx))
  }

  const [as, rs] = uniqueDifference(xs, removed)
  return [[x, ...as], rs]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to loop through `b` and apply `indexOf` with `splice` on each element.
Minimal working code would look like this:

```js
const diff = (a, b) => {
    //copy array to prevent mutations of inital array
    const temp = [...a]; 
    b.forEach(el => {
        let idx = temp.indexOf(el); //find element in a
        if (idx != -1) temp.splice(idx, 1); //if element found delete them
    });
    return temp;
};
const a = ["a", "a", "b"];
const b = ["a", "b"];
console.log(diff(a,b));

const a2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];
const b2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

console.log(diff(a2,b2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

See [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const a = ["a", "a", "b"];
const b = ["a", "b"];

const a2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
const b2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]



console.log(returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(a, b));
// [a]

console.log(returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(b, a));
// []

console.log(returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(a2,b2));
// [4]

console.log(returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(b2,a2));
// [3]

function returnAllElementsFromAThatAreNotInB(a, b) {
  const tempA = [...a];
  b.forEach((item) => {
    const matchIndex = tempA.findIndex((tempItem) => tempItem === item);
    if (matchIndex > -1) {
      tempA.splice(matchIndex, 1);
    }
  });

  return tempA
}
```